# Taking logarithms of variables

Tags: regression

It is common to taking logs of variables when perform a regression analysis. But the observations will become negative after logs transformation when it is less than 1. Is this the possible concerns?
(e.g. log(0.5) = -0.6931, but log(5)= 1.6094)

Comment: Can you use negative temperatures in a weather forecast or does it break the regression?

Comment: If your variables of concern are always positive, and your regression extrapolates to give a negative prediction, you could have problems.   But if you have taken logarithms and then get a negative prediction then take anti-logarithms (exponentiation if working in base $e$) of that to give you a positive result

Comment: @Henry I do not understand. Why would it be a concern that the predicted value of log of a variable is negative? This does not make the variable itself negative.

Comment: @denesp: exactly the opposite.  If you are modelling, for example, hours worked, and your extrapolation gives a negative result for certain circumstances, that may be an issue.  But if you are modelling logarithms of hours worked and your extrapolation gives a negative result for certain circumstances, that is less of a problem as it translates into a small positive number of hours ($\lt 1$)

Comment: What is the underlying problem you are tring to solve? The question as it stands is barely meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated already there is no problem if log(x) is negative. However, you would want to be careful if x=0 or if x<0 because then the logs are undefined. So as long as x>0 then there are no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, $\log(x)$ being negative is not a problem what so ever.